Linux, How to cleanup random duplicates?
b.txt =
copy of Substack web page
a file for text-to-speech software
no sorting of b.txt
sample text file, below:
Grace’s Substack  
details1  
  
Sam’s Newsletter:  
Sam’s Newsletter:  
details2  
  
Ned  
details3  
  
Sam’s Newsletter:  
Sam’s Newsletter:  
details4  
---  

Sam’s Newsletter: appears 4 times in b.txt is unwanted.
Sam’s Newsletter: appears 2 times in b.txt is desired.
How to filter out duplicate string when on next line?
Sam’s Newsletter: on Line4  = delete or space
Sam’s Newsletter: on Line5  = ok keep
Sam’s Newsletter: on Line11 = delete or space
Sam’s Newsletter: on Line12 = ok keep
command1
awk '!a[$0]++' b.txt > c.txt
is too aggressive because only
1 of 4 strings (Sam’s Newsletters) remains in file
3 of 4 strings are deleted using command1 unwanted
Sam’s Newsletter was deleted 3 times, unwanted
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30173/how-to-remove-duplicate-lines-inside-a-text-file
unwanted result:
Grace’s Substack  
details1  
  
Sam’s Newsletter:  
details2  
Ned  
details3  
details4  
---  

Can filter be done inplace?
and
How to get c.txt desired output?  see below
Grace’s Substack  
details1  
  
  
Sam’s Newsletter:  
details2  
  
Ned  
details3  
  
  
Sam’s Newsletter:  
details4  
---  

using
OS: Kubuntu 22.04.5 LTS x86_64
to display above:
neofetch --stdout |grep 'OS:'
--

<b.txt uniq


The uniq utility shall read an input file comparing adjacent lines, and write one copy of each input line on the output. The second and succeeding copies of repeated adjacent input lines shall not be written. The trailing <newline> of each line in the input shall be ignored when doing comparisons.
Repeated lines in the input shall not be detected if they are not adjacent.

(source)

Kamil answered the Question with
<b.txt uniq _
in addition, to mimic uniq -inplace we have:
cat b.txt | uniq > /tmp/result1.txt   then
mv --force /tmp/result1.txt b.txt
mv cleans-up Temp file /tmp/result1.txt
Note: delayed response because site in
read-only mode (scheduled maintenance).
